# Replace Nones in List with Values propagated from neighbors

Tags: python, pandas

I have a List:

`L = [-10,-9.8,-9.6, None, None, None, -8.8, -8.6, -8.4]`

How do I replace the Nones with values according to the propagation of the values so it looks like this:

`L = [-10,-9.8,-9.6, -9.4, -9.2, -9.0, -8.8, -8.6, -8.4]`

I tried using `pandas.fillna(method = ffill)` but it gives `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`
But this doesn't seem to be the right approach anyway.

Comment: You will need to interpolate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series([-10,-9.8,-9.6, None, None, None, -8.8, -8.6, -8.4]).interpolate()
```

yields:

```
0   -10.0
1    -9.8
2    -9.6
3    -9.4
4    -9.2
5    -9.0
6    -8.8
7    -8.6
8    -8.4
dtype: float64
```

To go back to a list:

```
pd.Series([-10,-9.8,-9.6, None, None, None, -8.8, -8.6, -8.4]).interpolate().tolist()
```